# Red box on Finder icon in Dock

Tags: finder, macos

Please see this image:

[image: red box in finder icon]

I don't know what's going on with that icon, but it has been persistent for the past week. It became like that when I forced the shutdown on my Mac because it hanged up. I've just upgraded to El Capitan when it happened.

I've tried the following:

- Reboot
- Relaunch Finder
- Quit Finder and Dock on Activity Terminal
- killall Dock

Nothing worked so far.

**Update:**

As per user24601's suggestion, I've tried the following:

- Turned on magnification. It persists on zoom. Please see image:

[image: magnified]

- Tried to change position. It still persists:

[image: vertical dock]

Comment: Interesting!  Did you try killall Dock in terminal?

Comment: Several times. I also found out that killing the Dock and relaunching Finder does not relaunch Dock. I just did it now, and while the behavior changed (Dock relaunched), the icon remains the same.

Comment: You might want to update your question with the steps you took already to try to fix it but without success.  Cheers!

Comment: If you turn on Dock Magnification, does the red box grow with the icon?

Comment: @user24601 yes, please see updated question.

Comment: If you go to Macintosh HD > System > Library > CoreServices > Finder (Control-click and select Show Package Contents) > Contents > Resources > Finder.icns, which should be the graphic for the app icon, does it have a red box too?

Comment: @user24601 it's normal.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up reporting it as **deeeeeeekun** suggested. Some of the suggested workaround in the comments were also suggested to me. This is the solution they gave that worked:

1) cd `getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR`

<strike>2) attach com.apple.dock.iconcache to radar</strike>

3) `rm com.apple.dock.iconcache; killall Dock`

I'll update the answer when they give me the reason why the redbox happened.

Answer (score 1):

It could well be a bug. You can try sending feedback to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a [Safe Mode](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/07/29/how-to-boot-mac-safe-mode/) startup (hold down the Shift key right after the start-up chime.)

Getting to the user Desktop may take longer than usual as there are several things OS X is doing during a Safe Mode such as checking the integrity of the boot disk and deleting cache files. Once Safe Mode finishes, restart.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with a half red/pink box on my finder icon (like a hat).

Just a 'killall Dock' command in the Terminal fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Looks a lot like an accessibility feature. Check under that section in System Preferences.